# Lookup across multiple columns & rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Vlookup's limitation is that it searches for a value down a single column. I need to search across multiple columns and multiple rows.

I have data in the following format:

```
HOST1    Guest1    Guest2    Guest3    Guest4
HOST2    Guest5    Guest6    Guest7    Guest8
```

I need to convert it down to two column pairs like this:

```
Guest1    Host1
Guest2    Host1
Guest3    Host1
```

So I want to lookup the guest's name in the range, b1:e2 in the first example.
Then grab the row number, and grab the value of {A$rownumber}.

Is it possible to do this kind of multicolumn, multirow search? Or are all the searches limited to one-dimensional vectors?

Comment: would your example return all guests under one host? Would Guest4 be included?

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't elaborate fully. The point is to have two columns, "guest" and the corresponding "host" for all values of guest. Assume that I have a separate column which includes all guests.

Answer (score 0):

The way for double lookups is to use `INDEX(MATCH(...), MATCH(...))`.
in Excel 2003 you can even activate the Lookup Wizard that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I made a user form with a combobox called ComboBox1 and a textbox called TextBox1 (multiline property enabled). When you load the user form (UserForm1) you the Initialize event will fire executing UserForm_Initialize(). That will populate the combobox with all the hosts. When you select a host the ComboBox1_Change() event will fire and output something like `HOST2    Guest5    Guest6    Guest7    Guest8` to the text box. But ofcourse you can change the output to be anywhere you want.

```
Option Explicit

Dim allHosts As Range
Private pHostRow As Integer
Dim hostColumn As Integer

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim Host As Range

    Dim firstHost As Range
    Dim lastHost As Range

    Dim lastHostRow As Integer

    hostColumn = 1

    Set firstHost = Cells(1, hostColumn)
    lastHostRow = firstHost.End(xlDown).Row

    Set lastHost = Cells(lastHostRow, hostColumn)
    Set allHosts = Range(firstHost, lastHost)

    For Each Host In allHosts
        ComboBox1.AddItem Host.Text
    Next Host

End Sub
```

.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim selectedHost As String
    selectedHost = ComboBox1.Text

    pHostRow = allHosts.Find(selectedHost).Row

    Dim guest As Range
    Dim allGuests As Range
    Dim firstGuest As Range
    Dim lastGuest As Range
    Dim lastGuestCol As Integer

    Dim Host As Range
    Set Host = Cells(pHostRow, hostColumn)
    lastGuestCol = Host.End(xlToRight).Column

    Set firstGuest = Host.Offset(0, 1)
    Set lastGuest = Cells(pHostRow, lastGuestCol)
    Set allGuests = Range(firstGuest, lastGuest)

    TextBox1.Text = selectedHost

    For Each guest In allGuests
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & selectedHost & guest.Text & vbCrLf
         'if you weren't outputting this to a textbox you wouldn't use the vbCrLf,
         'instead you would iterate to the next line in your output range.
    Next guest

End Sub
```

You can see how you can modify this so you would iterate through all the hosts (i.e. while populating the combobox) and for each host call the ComboBox1_Change() event (renamed of course and made a regular sub) to output all the guests to some range that you are iterating through on another worksheet.

Hope it helps!